# In swift, do we need "@MainActor in" inside the closure of an other object written inside ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, actor, mainactor

I have seen code like this

```swift
func connectVCAndVM() {
    // Setting up a closure to be called when data in the viewModel changes
    viewModel.dataChanged = { [weak self] in

        Task { @MainActor in
            // Reloading the tableView when data changes
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Do we need "@MainActor in" here? If the task is written inside viewcontroller, wouldn't the task automatically be executed in main thread due to context inheritance? I am learning about Actors so consider this as a newbie doubt.

Comment: Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: To execute whatever is inside the task in main thread. 
From my understanding, i dont need it.
But when i was checking some articles, I saw similar code being used. So wanted to be sure whether my understanding was correct :-)

Comment: Are you trying to replace `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: Yes, kind of. That was the intention.
But my doubt is do we need to do so?

Comment: It really depends on which thread is called `dataChanged`.

Comment: So if it's called as a result of a loading data from network which is in background thread, then we will need @MainActor?

Comment: So the goal is to reduce or eliminate calls to `DispatchQueue.main.async` to ensure we're on the main thread, replacing them with Swift concurrency instead. The way you've done it is not a bad way; we've done this sort of thing in our app. Whether there is in reality a chance that this method would have been called _not_ on the main thread depends on how the view model is implemented, as Rob has said. But the `@MainActor` does no harm in any case.

Comment: Generally, it's a good practice to not make any assumptions. Here, the code in the View cannot make a safe assumption that the ViewModel invokes the closure on the main thread. So, yes – forcing the relevant code executing on the main thread is good practice. Alternatively, insert a precondition to check whether the closure actually runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon how the view model was written and how `dataChanged` was defined.

A view model’s entire purpose is to integrate with a view, and all view interaction must be done from the main thread, so we frequently write our view models so that the closures are invoked from the main thread only (explicitly, so you don’t need to do stuff like you’ve got here).

Personally, I would be inclined to define the closure as such:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel {
    var dataChanged: (@Sendable @MainActor () -> Void)?

    …
}
```

That way, both the view and the view model understand that this closure will be invoked on the main actor.

Then the view controller can simply:

```swift
func connectVCAndVM() {
    // Setting up a closure to be called when data in the viewModel changes
    viewModel.dataChanged = { [weak self] in
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. One reason **not** to write the dataChanged closure as @MainActor is if that closure needs to do some compute-intensive "heavy lifting" that would freeze the main thread while it is executed. In that case you would want the closure to be invoked on a background thread, and then wrap your UI code in a `@MainActor` task as in the OPs code.

Comment: I hear you, but respectfully disagree. When a VM needs to notify a view of some change, it should always do that on the main actor, IMHO. If the view really needs to initiate some slow, blocking work, it is only that (edge-case) which should be isolated to a separate actor (or put in a nonisolated async func or put in detached task or whatever), not the notification closure. (As an aside, a view really shouldn’t be performing slow, synchronous work, anyway.) In my opinion, the VM should not impose the burden upon the V that all the closures must manually bridge back to the main actor.

Comment: I guess you're right. I should have thought about separation of concerns. This closure would be provided by the view.

Comment: To be frank, I am not convinced that we can (or should!) make the general assumption that a ViewModel always provides changes on the main thread. I'm more supporting the idea that Views need to know where they need to execute code, and thus need to choose an appropriate actor or dispatch accordingly. More generally, a ViewModel just provides data. A Data Provider should not need to know the specific requirements of its observers. Note also, in SwiftUI @State can be changed on any thread.

Comment: Yeah, the Observation framework w `@State` handles this exceedingly well (tho I have other beefs with that framework). Re `@StateObject` and `ObservableObject`, Apple explicitly advises isolating to the main actor. And regarding UIKit/AppKit I think the case for isolating to main actor is even more compelling, IMHO (precisely to avoid encumbering the view with the sort of syntactic noise in the OP’s question). But your point is well taken.